# Submitted form via ajax always return TRUE of unchecked checkbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

I`m building an Symfony 2 app. There I have a form with one checkbox, which I want to submit via jquery ajax. Everything works fine but there is a problem with sending of real value of checkbox input to my controller. It can be checked or unchecked, but everytime there is a TRUE value.

Here is my JS code:

```
$( 'form' ).submit( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var values = {};
    $.each( $('input, select ,textarea', '#modal form'), function(i, field) {
        values[field.name] = field.value;
    });

    //when I send var "values" into firebug console, there is real value, but later in controller isnt

    $.ajax({
        type        : $(this).attr( 'method' ),
        url         : $(this).attr( 'action' ),
        data        : values,
        dataType    : "json",
        cache       : false,
        success     : function(response) {
            //some code
        }
    });
```

And here my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity');
    $slides = $repo->findAll();
    $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType($this->get('router')));

    if ( $request->isMethod( 'POST' ) ) {
        $form->handleRequest( $request );

        if ( $form->isValid() ) {
            $data = $form->getData();

           //In $data['active'], what is my checkbox field is always TRUE value :(

           //another operation with data...
           $response['something'] = something;
           return new JsonResponse( $response );
     }


     return array('slides'=>$slides,'form' => $form->createView());
}
```

The others fields (text, textarea), which I edit, are sent correctly into controller. Problem is only in checkbox field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically wouldn't send a checkbox value to the server if it is unchecked. For example change the Javascript to:

```
$.each( $('input, select ,textarea', '#modal form'), function(i, field) {
    if(!$(this).is(':checkbox') || $(this).is(':checked')) {
        values[field.name] = field.value;
    }
});
```

In the PHP:

```
if(isset($data['active'])) {
    // it was checked...
} else {
    // it was not checked...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After change my JS as you wrote, it works correctly. Edit PHP wasnt needed.